# How can I fix this ejs function

Tags: javascript, ejs

How come is not working to add another **<%** between an already opened **<%**?
This is my code:

```
<% function isDisabled(x) {
    return x.disabled == 1 ? "#disabled" : `/case/<%=x.id%>`;
} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```js
<% function isDisabled(x) {
    return x.disabled == 1 ? "#disabled" : `/case/${x.id}`;
} %>
```

Comment: I've tried that and it says undefined, but now I know why it was undefined, I didn't add a property "id" to the Object. Thanks for answering my question!